# Convert String referential datatype to real referential datatypes

Tags: kotlin, reference

I have the following dataclasses:

```kotlin
data class JsonNpc(
  val name: String,
  val neighbours: JsonPreferences
)

data class JsonPreferences(
  val loves: List<String>,
  val hates: List<String>
)
```

I have a list of these, and they reference each other through strings like:

```
[
JsonNpc(
  "first",
  JsonPreferences(
    listOf("second"),
    listOf()
  )
),
JsonNpc(
  "second",
  JsonPreferences(
    listOf(),
    listOf("first")
  )
)
]
```

**note that a likes b does not mean b likes a**
I also have the Dataclasses

```
data class Npc(
        val name: String,
        val neighbours: NeighbourPreferences,
)

data class NeighbourPreferences(
        val loves: List<Npc>,
        val hates: List<Npc>
)
```

And I want to convert the String reference types to the normal reference types.

What I have tried:

recursively creating the npcs (and excluding any that are already in the chain, as that would lead to infinite recursion):

Does not work, as the Npc can not be fully created and the List is immutable (I dont want it to be mutable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a way to do this. It did not work with Npc as a data class, as I needed a real constructor

```kotlin
fun parseNpcs(map: Map<String, JsonNpc>): Map<String, Npc> {
    val resultMap: MutableMap<String, Npc> = mutableMapOf()
    for (value in map.values) {
        if(resultMap.containsKey(value.name))
            continue
        Npc(value, map, resultMap)
    }
    return resultMap
}

class Npc(jsonNpc: JsonNpc, infoList: Map<String, JsonNpc>, resultMap: MutableMap<String, Npc>) {
    val name: String
    val neighbourPreferences: NeighbourPreferences
    init {
        this.name = jsonNpc.name
        resultMap[name] = this

        val lovesNpc = jsonNpc.neighbours.loves.map {
            resultMap[it] ?: Npc(infoList[it] ?: error("Missing an Npc"), infoList, resultMap)
        }

        val hatesNpc = jsonNpc.neighbours.hates.map {
            resultMap[it] ?: Npc(infoList[it] ?: error("Missing an Npc"), infoList, resultMap)
        }

        this.neighbourPreferences = NeighbourPreferences(
                lovesNpc, hatesNpc
        )
    }
}

data class NeighbourPreferences(
        val loves: List<Npc>,
        val hates: List<Npc>
)
```

checking in the debugger, the people carry the same references for each Neighbour, so the Guide is always one Npc instance.